# Incorrect line number in Xcode Organizer Crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-organizer

How can I debug app crashes with Xcode (10) Organizer Crash Logs since the code has changed and I get incorrect line of error when opening a crash from there?

Also, what is that X in "method() + X" title of the crash? The line number of error surely it isn't, I checked that.

And please tell me some tricks & advices on how to make use of this feature offered by Xcode at its best. I'm using swift.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post the error log if any.

Comment: You are supposed to archive every version you released so you can symbolicate your crash log based on that version. And watch this WWDC video for bunch of tips: [Understanding Crashes and Crash Logs](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/414/)

Comment: The X in `method() + X` means X assembly instructions into the method. You have to disassembly the method in the same version as your crash log. Again, you can find that in the WWDC video